# Elasticsearch namedtuple conflicts with python "from"

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using some namedtuples in my program to store data that will be written out later to query dsl.  I'm having trouble with the word "from".  When I use it as a field name in a namedtuple I get this when trying to access it:

```
ValueError: Type names and field names cannot be a keyword: 'from'
```

The obvious answer is to put an underscore after it to avoid the conflict,
but then I need to traverse the entire query structure just before sending to elasticsearch to s/r any instance of "from_" to "from", of which there can be several and at varying levels.  I already tried just using it with the underscore and it doesn't work.

I am wondering if maybe elasticsearch has a way to specify an "alias" for keys in situations like this?  Or maybe even a built-in way I don't know about?

I'm using the elasticsearch-py module.

One of the big affected areas is aggregations:

```
  "price" : {
     "range" : {
        "field" : "price",
        "ranges" : [
           {
              "to" : 20
           },
           {
              "to" : 50,
              "from" : 20
           },
           {
              "from" : 50,
              "to" : 100
           },
           {
              "to" : 200,
              "from" : 100
           },
           {
              "from" : 200
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

This isn't the exact code I am using, but a simplified version which illustrates what I am doing.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def convert(dictionary):
    return namedtuple('GenericDict', dictionary.keys())(**dictionary)

ranges = [
    {
        'to': 20
    },
    {
        'from': 20,
        'to': 50
    },
    {
        'from': 50,
        'to': 100
    },
    {
        'from': 100,
        'to': 200
    },
    {
        'from': 200
    }
]
for i in range(len(ranges)):
    ranges[i] = convert(ranges[i])
```

I guess the other answers are a) use elasticsearch-dsl to build queries and/or b) don't used namedtuples for this.  But I'd like to stick with the approach I'm taking, and just wondering if there's a simple solution

Comment: Are you using the official [elasticsearch-py client library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) or something else? Can you share some sample code that fails for you?

Comment: Thanks, yes, using the elasticsearch-py module.  I updated my OP with sample code to illustrate.